SSIS Data Flow OData Source encountering error because some columns start with a number
Hopefully someone can advise me on how to resolve this issue. There are two caveats here:

I am a front-end developer who is comfortable with basic SQL Server operations, but I have no experience with SSIS. I'm just trying to help out the backend team because they are slammed and I'm trying my best to learn this on my own and on-the-fly.
The OData source cannot be altered directly. We only have read access.

So, in the Data Flow I have an OData Source. In the OData Source Editor, I have selected the desired Collection. BUT I get an error when I either try to Preview or go to Columns. The specific error is:

Name cannot begin with the '1' character, hexadecimal value 0x31.

Upon further investigation I was able to determine that several column names in this particular table start with numbers which seems to be the problem. I tried to use Query Options to only select the columns that don't have numbers, but even if that worked (which it didn't) that's not really a fix in this case because I need the offending columns. Is there a way to rename the columns or give them an alias that will get me past this error? Ultimately I'm trying to bring the OData source into an OLE DB Destination.
A screenshot of the error is attached.


Are the column names surrounded by []?  Or you can select the column name as alias so it wont start with a number?

@Brad, I tried using $select=1stPass AS FirstPass but that didn't work. I could not find anywhere in my searching that creating an alias is possible in this manner, or if it is possible, that this would be the proper format. I did try surrounding the column name with [] and that also did not work.
